# installed npm installed module not recognised by angular

Tags: node.js, angular, npm-install

So I am attempting to install a npm package into my angular cli project.

https://npm.runkit.com/ng2-dropdown-multiselect

i have ran the command to install in npm and save the module.

I have verified it is in my packages. I have imported it into my app module and have  decleared it into my imports array:

```
npm install --save ng2-dropdown-multiselect
suitsandtables@0.0.0 /home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/frontend/suitsandtables
└── ng2-dropdown-multiselect@1.2.0 

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN worker-loader@0.8.1 requires a peer of webpack@>=0.9 <2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0 but none was installed.
```

now import

```
import {DropdownMultiselectModule} from 'ng2-dropdown-multiselect';

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    PdfViewerModule,
    DropdownMultiselectModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
```

but nothing. the text in the import: `{DropdownMultiselectModule}`

should be orange if it was referenced properly, but its white meaning a failed import. I look at the docs and I am doing everything right. I look at the other packages I have imported and I am doing everything right.

anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: When you say it should be orange are you referring to IDE highlighting? I noticed some IDE's do not immediately pick up npm installs and require you to switch to another window to pick it up. if the code still compiles via ng serve and the app still renders then you're in the clear :)

Comment: correct. And Ok I will close the window and see again

Comment: closed and reopened the window and it didn't work

Comment: im going to try another package see what happens

Comment: Are the dependencies for that package installed?

Comment: what's your angular version?

Comment: I tried on my local machine and I got the same behavior. It's odd for sure. Additionally I would caution against using this package since it is marked as `no longer maintained`

Comment: @zmanc thank you I went with another package. I appreciate you.

Comment: Awesome, i added it as an answer so you can select it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried on my local machine and I got the same behavior. It's odd for sure. Additionally I would caution against using this package since it is marked as no longer maintained

Comment: indeed tried it on my local machine did not got it working, and also found the comment of no longer maintained

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad package verified by me and another. I went with another and it worked fine. The one I went with is:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown

Comment: also true, i tried this package, a few minutes and it was up and running